# Average case of determing whether a number is prime (not with optimal algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

I have the following function which determines whether a number is prime or not. I know that the best time complexity for this is O((logN)^6) but the following algorithm is a much simpler one. I also know it has a worst case of O(sqrt(N)) and I am trying to think about it's average case complexity. I need an explanation/proof for the answer. Here is my function and a basic program to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int isprime(int N){
    int j;
    if(N==2){
        return 1;
    }
    for(j=2;j<=ceil(sqrt(N));j++){
        if(N%j==0){
            return 0;//false, number is not prime
        }
    }
    return 1;//true, number is prime
}
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<100;i++){
        printf("Number: %d \t %d\n",i,isprime(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The example is in C but I care about the algorithmic part of the problem so I have not included any programming language's name in the tags.

Comment: Hint: how many numbers are dividable by 2? How many are dividable by 3, but not by 2? How many are dividable by ... and not by ...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's how I tried to think about it too. That the probability of the algorithm ending in the first repetition is 1/2, the probability of it ending in the second one is 1/6, the probability of it ending in the third one is 0(since if a number is dividable by 4 it is also dividable by 2), but afterwards and especially for larger numbers the problem becomes too complicated to think this way

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50326/what-is-the-average-case-complexity-of-trial-division